# One font not working using CSS @font-face while the other does

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Currently have 2 fonts I'm trying to use for my website, Quicksand and Roboto Mono. I've declared 2 @font-face's with a link to the source file for each, Quicksand works perfectly but Roboto Mono doesn't I've checked class names and tested that the CSS is being applied to the text which it is, other fonts can be applied to the text but when trying to use Roboto Mono it doesn't work. Quicksand works perfectly when I'm using it in the exact same way so I'm not sure what the problem is.

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: RobotoMono;
  src: url(fonts/Roboto.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: QuickSand;
  src: url(fonts/Quicksand.ttf);
}

.Blue-title{
  color: #75bbf0;
  font-family: RobotoMono;
}

.Main-title{
  color: #cae1f3;
  font-size: 75pt;
  font-family: Quicksand;
}
```

**HTML (React)**

```
<h2 className="Blue-title">Hi, my name is</h2> //only applies color
<h1 className="Main-title">REDACTED</h1> //works fine
```

Comment: you have a typo in your `font-family` declaration. It's `QuickSand` but you're using `Quicksand` in your css

Comment: @Airah yea i did notice that but Quicksand is the font working correctly and fixing the typo doesn't fix the other font, Quicksand was working with and without the typo surprisingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

*Need to check your folder structure how you made for font file.

so this code might help you... cheers

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&family=Roboto&family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');

.Blue-title{
  color: #75bbf0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;;
}

.Main-title{
  color: #cae1f3;
  font-size: 75pt;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="Blue-title">Hi, my name is</h2>
<h1 class="Main-title">REDACTED</h1>
```

Comment: yeah i did notice this as well but Quicksand is the font that is working correctly, could this still be causing the error with the other font?

Comment: @DarcyPower : Please check the code now and Run code snippet and see.